# Selfoss says "no entries found"

Tags: php, rss

I installed [selfoss](http://selfoss.aditu.de/) as instructed in the readme, set up the rss feeds, but I get "no entries found" when I open it.

Anyone got this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that selfoss does not like the way feedburner gives the feed if BrowserFriendly is enabled.

Just add ?fmt=xml at the end of the RSS url and it works

Another reason is that you could forget to cron wget your.selfoss.url/update